# ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine issue

Tags: c#

In a System.Windows.Forms.Panel (in C# and .NET 4.5.1) I have to follow the cursor position with two crossing perpendicular lines.
Using ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine somtimes parts or whole old lines persist.
This happen in a random manner and applying or not the style:

SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true)

as suggested in MSDN.

Temporarily solved using a cross cursor but I have to do it.
If anyone can give me hint...
Thank you
D.R.

Comment: I see trolls coming up

Answer (score 0):

Forget `DrawReversibleLine`!

This will do what you told us you want to do:

```
Point mouse = Point.Empty;

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouse = e.Location;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouse != Point.Empty)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0, mouse.Y, panel1.ClientSize.Width, mouse.Y );
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, mouse.X, 0,  mouse.X, panel1.ClientSize.Height );
    }
}

private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mouse = Point.Empty;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

But it will **not** do what you **didn't** tell us.

Note: You will need to update anthing else on **drawn** that Panel - I hope there is nothing, otherwise it needs to be redrawn from the `Paint` event..

Comment: Unfortunately I have no time, right now but I think that there has been a misunderstanding. What I need is the old XOR ROP2 line drawing to draw a line over all the control and then delete it to be redrawn in an other place. But there is not any ROP drawing in GDI+.

Comment: Yes, this has gone together with the graphic chips, like the ET4000,  that suppoerted it so well and other no so nice things. But for losing this level of control we have gained the refresh services Windows provides and real fast machines.. - To ensure visiblity you can add a 2nd pair of lines with a brighter color and to leave the image below untouched simply use a PictureBox instead of the Panel; that's what it's for..

Comment: @TaW: your code does not erase the previous line.  I'm trying to solve this problem at the moment and looking for a XOR type solution.

Comment: @S Meaden: No XOR any longer; this is because the graphics hardware that once supported it is gone and speed is so much better that it is no longer needed. Still unfortunate. - Sure, my code __implicitly does__ erase any previous drawing. If you have a problem do post a question describing it with the code you are using!

Comment: @TaW: Thanks for invite, I only post questions when I'm sure I'm stuck otherwise they're sure to be downvoted for missing something obvious.

Comment: Yeah, well that can happen. If you have any questons, feel free to ping me.

Comment: @TaW: Thanks.  It looks like using Cursors.Cross will get me more or less there.